# Finding position of Nth element in array

Tags: php

So I have the following array:

```
$ISBN = '0,1,9,8,5,x,8,0,3,0';
$inArray = explode(',',$ISBN);
```

And I need to find the `x` character in it. I'm doing it like so:

```
foreach ($inArray as $element) {
    if (!is_numeric($element)){
        $unknown = $element;
        echo $unknown;
        exit();
    }
}
```

However, what I actually want to do is find the position of the `x` character in the array, given that it could be in range of 1 to 10. It's probably something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: `$ISBN` isn't an array.  It's a string.  Why not just simply do `$arr = explode(',', $ISBN);  echo array_search('x', $arr);`?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($inArray as $index => $element) {
    if (!is_numeric($element)){
        echo "Array index: ".$index;
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Will accept the answer as soon as possible. Thanks for you time :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $ISBN = '0,1,9,8,5,x,8,0,3,0';

    echo $key = array_search('x', explode(",",$ISBN));

?>
```

Output:

```
5
```